# Ionic Checking Internet connection

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
  connectionerror($ionicPopup)
    })

      // display error msg and close the app.
      function connectionerror($ionicPopup){
          $ionicPopup.alert({
              title: "Network Error",
              content: "No internet connection",
              okText: 'Retry',
          })
          .then(function(result) {

           //do something

          });
      }
```

What I would like to do is that when I click on 'retry' for it to check if there is internet connection again. If there is, to load the page normally, if no internet connection to keep the popup open. Also, how can I apply this to all the page?

Comment: show a bit of what you have done

Comment: that's pretty much it, im not even sure how to start, i am new at this

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Ionic Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) , you could use something like :

```
var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
template: '--yourTemplate--',
title: 'Network Error',
subTitle: 'No internet connection'
buttons: [
  { text: 'Cancel' },
  {
    text: '<b>Retry</b>',
    type: 'button-positive',
    onTap: function(e) {
      if (!$rootScope.checkConnection() ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        // Juste go wherever you want with $state.go(), or reload the current page;
      }
    }
  }
]
```

});

Just write the $rootScope.checkConnection() function to check network status

Comment: thank you, do you happen to know how I can put a function for the 'cancel' button. On cancel, I would like them to '  ionic.Platform.exitApp();'

Comment: Just add an "onTap" function with the first buttons object :
buttons: [
  { text: 'Cancel',
    onTap: function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         //Here your code to exit app
    },
  {
    text: '<b>Retry</b>',
    type: 'button-positive',
    onTap: function(e) {
      if (!$rootScope.checkConnection() ) {
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        // Juste go wherever you want with $state.go(), or reload the current page;
      }
    }
  }